# Bootstrap/Razor Segundo panel faz collapse no primeiro

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

[image: O código é este]
O que acontece é que tenho 2 topicos na base dados que sao inseridos automaticamente na pagina e atá aqui tudo bem,mas começando com os paines fechados ou abertos se clicar no segundo ele abre/fecha sempre o primeiro...bootstrap e afins nao é muito o meu forte.Obrigado

Comment: Poste o código, imagem não ajuda.

Comment: Só vejo um painel. Onde está o segundo?

Answer (score 0):

O segundo esta no segundo ciclo do foreach, o que me estava a acontecer é que nao estava a incrementar o id do panel-collapse, então qualquer um que clicka-se para abrir ele ia sempre ao id do primeiro.

apenas acrescentei e incrementei a variavel 'i'.

```
    @{
        int i = 1;
        foreach (TopicoDb t in Model)
        {
        i++;
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#1B2B30;color:darkorange;">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1@(i)">@t.Titulo </a>
                        <span class="badge" style="text-align:right;">@t.Respostas.Count() </span>
                    </h4>

                </div>
                <div id="collapse1@(i)" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <!--TEXTO CAIXA COMMENTS e RESPOSTAS no PAINEL BODY-->
                        <p style="color:darkgray;font-size:10px;">Inserido por: @t.User.userName</p>
                        <br />
                        <p>@t.TextoDescritivo</p>
                        <hr />
                        @if (Session["UserLogged"] != null)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Resposta", "Home"))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                @Html.Hidden("topicoId", t.Id)
                                @Html.Label("Responder:", new { style = "font-size:14px" })
                                <br />
                                @Html.TextArea("MsgResposta", "", 5, 140, new { })
                                <br />
                                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
                            }

                            <hr />
                            foreach (var resposta in t.Respostas)
        {
                                <p style="font-size:10px;">Respondido por: @resposta.User.userName</p>
                                <p>@resposta.MsgResposta</p>
                                <hr />
                            }

    }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso é uma resposta ou parte da pergunta?

Comment: Foi a resposta q acabei por descobrir ,a minha pergunta.